# ssh bash -c redirection to file not working

Tags: bash

I am trying to execute a command (which includes a redirection) over ssh.

this does not work as expected. it creates the file `/tmp/world.txt` but it's empty:

```
ssh myuser@myserver.com bash -c "echo hello >/tmp/world.txt"
```

this works as expected:

```
echo "echo hello >/tmp/world.txt" | ssh myuser@myserver.com bash -s
```

what is the problem with the first command?

Comment: run it like `ssh myuser@myserver.com 'bash -c "echo hello >/tmp/world.txt"'`

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.